# Converting multiple rows to columns with specific column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a few items that are being issued (I-UN) and wasted (W-WS) regularly at different date/time. I was going to keep a transaction time for each time( W-WS minus I-UN), so in order to do accomplish it, I need the I-UN Date and W-WS in separate columns.

Below is what I have:

```
    ItemID  Type    Date
    441455  I-UN    3/24/19 8:00
    441455  W-WS    3/24/19 8:09
    441455  I-UN    3/24/19 9:47
    441455  W-WS    3/24/19 9:51
    441455  I-UN    3/24/19 12:20
    441455  W-WS    3/24/19 12:26
    441455  I-UN    3/24/19 15:50
    441455  W-WS    3/24/19 15:53
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
    ItemID  I-UN Date       W-WS Date
    441455  3/24/19 8:00    3/24/19 8:09
    441455  3/24/19 9:47    3/24/19 9:51
    441455  3/24/19 12:20   3/24/19 12:26
    441455  3/24/19 15:50   3/24/19 15:53
```

Is there a way I can query to get my desired result? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to achieve this unless you can tell us the business rule for aligning the two values.  There are mulitple W-WS which can be matched with a given I-UN

Comment: This isn't a PIVOT, this is a simple self-join.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self-join of the table to itself, with the `I-UN` rows on the left side, and the TOP 1 `W-WS` row on the right side, with the `Date` of the right side > the `Date` of the left side.

As an alternate to a self-join, you could just select the `I-UN` rows in your FROM..WHERE clause, and get the `W-WS Date` with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a full join on the item ID and the `row_number()` ordered by the time.

```
SELECT t1.itemid [ItemID],
       t1.date [I-UN Date],
       t2.date [W-WS Date]
       FROM (SELECT itemid,
                    date,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date) r#
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE type = 'I-UN') t1
            FULL JOIN (SELECT itemid,
                              date,
                              row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date) r#
                              FROM elbat
                              WHERE type = 'W-WS') t2
                      ON t1.itemid = t2.itemid
                         AND t1.r# = t2.r#;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04b1440cb3a9e9fddae43e427926b113)

Or probably an inner join if you only want pairs where both times exist (or a left or right join if you only want to make sure that all times are taken for one of them).